# Mootools support for selector chaining?

Tags: jquery, mootools

Does Mootools support pseudo-class selector chaining either natively or with a plugin?  In jQuery, for example:

```
$("div:first-child:visible:contains('chocolate chip cookie') > h1")
```

I know this can be accomplished by chaining method calls but I'm really after having all of the selectors within the string.

Comment: Doesn't appear to natively. The selector engine gets completely borked with multiple pseudo selectors. Go to http://demos.mootools.net/Mouseenter and try in your console `$$('p:first-child')` (works) then `$$('p:contains(demo)')` (works), then try combining them: `$$('p:first-child:contains(demo)')` (borked. Should get nothing back).

Comment: That's what I thought.  I guess I was just hoping a patch or something was on the way.  If I was a little more experienced I might try patching it myself.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @CrescentFresh I'm afraid you're wrong, chaining pseudo-selectors in MooTools works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not natively.

*I added this per Crescent Fresh's comment above.*

Answer (score 0):

Considering that `:visible` is a jQuery invention, and not a real pseudo-selector, the provided example works just fine with MooTools.

That said, it's MooTools, you can extend it pretty easily to implement a `:visible` pseudo-selector:

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/X2xcx/